# Uso correto do método onChildRemoved em ChildEventListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, event-listener

Boa noite! Estou fazendo um app de chat e eu listo as conversas em um recyclerview. Optei por usar o método addChildEventListener, pois(eu acho) que isso irá consumir menos recursos uma vez que os dados só serão atualizados se houver mudança no firebase. Eu consigo adicionar as conversas normalmente mas encontrei um problema ao excluir. Quando excluo uma das conversas o meu recyclerview com a lista de conversas não atualiza e ela continua aparecendo na lista mesmo após ser deletada do firebase. A lista só é atualizada se eu fecho e abro o meu app novamente. Eu sei que devo fazer algo dentro do método onChildRemoved, mas eu não sei como fazer a lista ser atualizada. Esse é o meu método.

```
public void recuperarConversasPareamento(){

    try {

        listaConversas.clear();
        childEventListenerChat = conversasParearExibicao.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.i("retornoChat", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Conversa conversa = ds.getValue(Conversa.class);
                    Log.i("retornoChat2", conversa.getUsuarioExibicao().getApelido());
                    Log.i("retornoChat2", conversa.getUsuarioExibicao().getEmail());
                    listaConversas.add(conversa);                    }

                adapter.notifyItemInserted(listaConversas.size());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Conversa conversa = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversa.class);
                listaConversas.remove(conversa);
                Log.i("log", "O dado foi removido");
                Log.i("retornoChatRemovido", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } 
        });

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("erro-recuperarListaChat", e.getMessage());
    }
```

E essa é a estrutura de mensagens que estou recuperando no firebase. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Ainda não descobri a melhor forma de se usar o onChildRemoved, mas como medida paliativa estou atualizando o fragment manualmente sempre que há uma remoção. Para isso adicionei as linhas de código dentro do método onChildRemoved pois ele só é acionado quando um filho é removido. As linhas para atualizar o fragment(ou a sua activity) também podem ser colocadas após o seu método de remover o item porque acaba dando no mesmo.

```
@Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i("log", "REMOVIDO COM SUCESSO");
                Log.i("dadoRemovido", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                /*Atualiza a tela do fragment após remover*/
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(ChatFragment.this).attach(ChatFragment.this).commit();

            }
```